# Sharepoint : Google webchart not appearing from list?

Tags: sharepoint, google-visualization, sharepoint-online

I got sharepoint online working under O365, In our home page we need a chart showing the summary of our list data

I am trying to follow the below steps in my list
https://www.evoketechnologies.com/blog/visualizing-sharepoint-google-charts/

```
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
&lt;script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" type="text/javascript"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js" type="text/javascript"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script language="javascript"&gt;
var returnedItems = null;
function loadGoogleLibAndDraw(){
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar','line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(visualizeData);
}
function visualizeData() {
var context = new SP.ClientContext();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(document.getElementById('Project Issues').value);
var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
caml.set_viewXml("&lt;View&gt;&lt;/View&gt;");
 
returnedItems = list.getItems(caml);
context.load(returnedItems);
context.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback, onFailedCallback);
}
function onSucceededCallback(sender, args) {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Status');
data.addColumn('number', 'PercentComplete');
var enumerator = returnedItems.getEnumerator();
var markup = '';
while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
var row = [];
var listItem = enumerator.get_current();
row.push(listItem.get_item('Status'));
row.push(listItem.get_item('PercentComplete'));
data.addRow(row);
}
var options = {
chart: {
title: 'Sales Trend',
},
bars: 'vertical'
};
var barChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('BarChart'));
barChart.draw(data, options);
 
var lineChart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('LineChart'));
lineChart.draw(data, options);
}
 
function onFailedCallback(sender, args) {
var markup = '&lt;p&gt;The request failed: &lt;br&gt;';
markup += 'Message: ' + args.get_message() + '&lt;br&gt;';
displayDiv.innerHTML = markup;
}
&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;/head&gt;
 
&lt;body onload="loadGoogleLibAndDraw()"&gt;
&lt;form name="metricsform" id="metricsform"&gt;
&lt;input id="customListName" name="customListName" value="Project Issues" type="hidden"/&gt;
&lt;/form&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div id="displayDiv"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div id="BarChart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div id="LineChart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
```

I embeded the above script to my sharepoint page , replacing listname,column names but its not showing any chart from my list but giving an error as below
[image]

Thank you

Comment: @WhiteHat , The snippet displays the code in the result not the chart

Comment: why are all the html tags escaped? is that required? can you get any code to work in that manner?

Comment: i am following this ,  https://www.evoketechnologies.com/blog/visualizing-sharepoint-google-charts/

Comment: maybe try adding the code with the tags not escaped

Comment: Now its white screen . nothing shows

Comment: I was able to fix it, as html is not properly escaped

Answer (score 0):

@aryan,

Please have a try below code, i am able to get the chart works.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var returnedItems = null;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            loadGoogleLibAndDraw();
        });

        function loadGoogleLibAndDraw() {
            google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar', 'line'] });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(visualizeData);
        }
        function visualizeData() {
            var context = new SP.ClientContext();
            var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('smartphone_sales');
            var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
            caml.set_viewXml("<View></View>");

            returnedItems = list.getItems(caml);
            context.load(returnedItems);
            context.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback, onFailedCallback);
        }
        function onSucceededCallback(sender, args) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Red Mi3');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Honor 5s');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Le 1s');
            var enumerator = returnedItems.getEnumerator();
            var markup = '';
            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                var row = [];
                var listItem = enumerator.get_current();
                row.push(listItem.get_item('Title'));
                row.push(listItem.get_item('RedMi3'));
                row.push(listItem.get_item('Honor5s'));
                row.push(listItem.get_item('Le1s'));
                data.addRow(row);
            }
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    title: 'Sales Trend',
                },
                bars: 'vertical'
            };
            var barChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('BarChart'));
            barChart.draw(data, options);

            var lineChart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('LineChart'));
            lineChart.draw(data, options);
        }

        function onFailedCallback(sender, args) {
            var markup = '<p>The request failed: <br>';
            markup += 'Message: ' + args.get_message() + '<br>';
            displayDiv.innerHTML = markup;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div id="displayDiv"></div>
        <div id="BarChart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
        <div id="LineChart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Test Result:

[image]

Please make sure the column's internal name in your code is correct. And you may check the source panel to see if the JS files have been loaded. Sometimes it will remains some caches, so please refresh the page or try it in a private window.

BR